# Complex integral result and its asymptotes

Tags: asymptotics, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I need to perform the following complex integral analytically,
$$
I_n(\nu) := \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d} k}{2\pi} \; \frac{ e^{i k n} }{\nu + cos(k) + i \eta^+} ~,
\tag{*}
$$
where $i = \sqrt{-1}$, $ n \in \mathbb{N} > 0 $, $\nu \in \mathbb{R}$, $| \nu | > 1$, and $\eta^+ \rightarrow 0^+$. The latter limit should be taken *after* obtaining the value of the integral.

I have tried to perform the integral by the standard methods used in the calculus of residues; namely, by mapping $I_n$ to a contour integral via a variable change,
$$
z := e^{i k} ~,
$$
so that $|z| = 1$ and $\mathrm{d} k = \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{i z}$ for $ z \neq 0$, and
$$
cos(k) = \frac{e^{i k} + e^{-i k}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} (z + \frac{1}{z}) ~.
$$
Then,
$$
 I_n(\nu) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \, \oint_{C_1} \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{z} \; \frac{z^n}{\nu + \frac{1}{2}(z + \frac{1}{z}) + i \eta^+} ,
$$
where $C_1$ is the *unit circle* centred at the origin, $z = 0$.
The result of the integral will be then the residue of the (simple) poles *inside* the unit circle.

For $|\nu| > 1$, I find the poles inside $C_1$ as
$$
z^- = - \nu - \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1} + i\eta^+ \quad \text{for} \quad \nu < 0, \\
z^+ = - \nu + \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1} + i\eta^+ \quad \text{for} \quad \nu > 0 ~,
$$
with the residues,
$$
\mathrm{Res}(z^-) = \frac{ (-\nu - \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1})^n }{-2 \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1}} , \\
\mathrm{Res}(z^+) = \frac{ (-\nu + \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1})^n }{2 \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1}} ~.
$$
Therefore, the integral yields (for $ |\nu| > 1 $)
$$
I_n(\nu) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{ (-\nu - \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1})^n }{- \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1}}  &, \nu < 0 \\
\frac{ (-\nu + \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1})^n }{\sqrt{\nu^2 - 1}}  &, \nu > 0 
\end{cases}
~.
\tag{**}
$$
The problem is that the asymptotic behaviour does *not* match what I expect from the original expression (*); that is,
$$
I_n(\nu) \sim \frac{1}{\nu} \quad \text{for} \quad |\nu| \gg 1 ~,
$$
since this does *not* conform to the asymptotic behaviour of the results (**),
$$
I_n(|\nu| \gg 1) = 
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{ |\nu|^{n-1} } &, \nu < 0 \\
(-1)^n \, \frac{1}{ |\nu|^{n-1} }  &, \nu > 0 
\end{cases}
~,
$$
especially for positive $\nu$.

I'd like to understand which part of my calculation or reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: for big $\nu$, $-\nu+\sqrt{\nu^2-1}\sim 1$ and therefor the asymptotics is indeed $1/|\nu|$ since $\sqrt{\nu^2-1}\sim |\nu|$

Comment: @tired: I can't see how you have obtained such a result. I obtain the asymptotic form for $\nu > 1$ as follows:
$ \sqrt{\nu^2 - 1} \stackrel{\text{Taylor expansion}}{=} |\nu| (1 - \frac{1}{2 \nu^2}) \stackrel{\nu \gg 1}{\approx} |\nu| (1 - \frac{1}{\nu^2})$. Therefore, for *positive* $\nu$ in (**), one obtains the asymptote, $ \frac{ (-\nu + \nu (1 - \frac{1}{\nu^2}))^n }{|\nu|} = (-1)^n \frac{1}{|\nu|^{n-1}} $.